# Alternative to include file or require_once() in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP so don't know if there is any alternative to `require_once()`. My issue is: currently I am including database configuration file on almost each and every file which needs to connect with database using `require_once()`. I don't want to include my configuration file on each and every file because it may cause some security risk. Any kind of help would be apriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of security risk? If you need the data, you need to include it (or use environment variables, which will be more of a pain to set up)!

Comment: `require_once()` doesn't just display the source code in the browser, as though it were HTML. There is no security risk here, unless you `echo` the secure data (which only a fool would do).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was just worried about if someone able to hack any of my file, it will put my whole site into risk although I am trying every possibility which keeps me out of this. Thanks Matt.

Comment: setup your server right right and put sensitive files outside document root, because you try to fix the problem in wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the php.ini setting [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file) to automatically include files when the php process is started.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking for something like this.